# My laptop slows down when copying

Tags: laptop, copy

Laptop runs normaly until a start a copy. After that it slows a lot, I tried to download copy managers but I haven't found any. If I need to do something, I just pause the copy and after that I resume the copy and slows again. I use Kubuntu 18.04, system it's up to date. 
My laptop is a Samsung NP300E5E-S01ES, intel pentium dual core, RAM 4gb

Comment: Perhaps post your system specs. A copy operation should not strongly slow the system down.

Comment: That's why I'm posting this, my laptop it's a Samsung NP300E5E-S01ES, dual core and 4gb RAM. When I'm copying and try to open a new foldre takes more than 30 seconds to open Dolphin and then a few seconds to show content.

Comment: Is the opening of other programs also slowed down significantly, or is is just Dolphin? Same issue if you copy using the command line?

Comment: It slows everything else, and I copy mostly from an external HDD to another and it's very annoying to do anything else on the laptop during the copy. Also my kubuntu start up takes over 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually Totally Normal

When you copy files from one place to another on the same physical drive it means the disk heads have to move back and forth very quickly. When you add the need for the web browser to be accessing files in it's "Temporary Internet Files" folder you end up with the disk getting hammered by competing I/O requests - a condition known as "thrashing".

This is why a lot of people use a separate physical drive for the OS - it means that the OS drive can continue to respond quickly even though you're doing a lot of work with the data drive.

Another reason this might happen is that your HDD is facing problems, try this to check you hard disk health:-

1. Open Disks from the Activities overview.
2. Select the disk you want to check from the list of storage devices on the left. Information and status of the disk will be shown.
3. Click the menu button and select SMART Data & Self-Tests…. The Overall Assessment should say “Disk is OK”.
4. See more information under SMART Attributes, or click the Start Self-test button to run a self-test.

References:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en

Comment: I do not agree that it would be normal that a laptop slows significantly down while doing copy operations, expect on low end machines with limited memory.

Comment: @vanadium Though it may happen when you have a really crappy and slow HDD and you are using it to boot your OS too.

Comment: @Arunay Not sure. As soon as you have a decent processor and some RAM, copying processes normally should be 'niced' to the extent that you do not experience unbearable slowdowns.